# Get all values of arrays from mongo documents

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework, distinct

I have a mongo collection with documents containing arrays:

```
   { item: "journal", qty: 25, tags: ["blank", "red"], dim_cm: [ 14, 21 ] },
   { item: "notebook", qty: 50, tags: ["red", "blank"], dim_cm: [ 14, 21 ] },
   { item: "paper", qty: 100, tags: ["red", "blank", "plain"], dim_cm: [ 14, 21 ] },
   { item: "planner", qty: 75, tags: ["blank", "red"], dim_cm: [ 22.85, 30 ] },
   { item: "postcard", qty: 45, tags: ["blue"], dim_cm: [ 10, 15.25 ] }
```

I would like to get a single array containing all distinct values, such as:

tags: ["blank", "red", blue"] and dim_cm: [14,21,22.85,30,10,15.25]

Is this possible with an aggregation pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$group` with `$reduce` and `$setIntersection`:

1. `$group` all documents to create one array of arrays per key
2. flatten each array with `$reduce` and make it a set using `$setIntersection`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: null, tags: {$push: "$tags"}, dim_cm: {$push: "$dim_cm"}}},
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      tags: {
        $setIntersection: [
          {$reduce: {
              input: "$tags",
              initialValue: [],
              in: {$concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"]}
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      dim_cm: {
        $setIntersection: [
          {$reduce: {
              input: "$dim_cm",
              initialValue: [],
              in: {$concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"]}
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Qez-c9Oo8g8)

Another way is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$tags"},
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      tags: {$addToSet: "$tags"},
      dim_cm: {$addToSet: "$dim_cm"
    }
  },
  {$unwind: "$dim_cm"},
  {$unwind: "$dim_cm"},
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      tags: {$first: "$tags"},
      dim_cm: {$addToSet: "$dim_cm"}
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground - unwind](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UdM4OmQ9LQV)

Which you can split into two queries which will be much faster:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$tags"},
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      tags: {$addToSet: "$tags"}
    }
  },
])
```

A 3rd option is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      arr: {
        $concatArrays: [
          {$map: {input: "$tags", as: "item", in: {k: "tag",  v: "$$item"}}},
          {$map: {input: "$dim_cm", as: "item", in: {k: "dim_cm", v: "$$item"}}}
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {$unwind: "$arr"},
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      tags: {
        $addToSet: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$arr.k", "tag"]}, "$arr.v", "$$REMOVE"]}
      },
      dim_cm: {
        $addToSet: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$arr.k", "dim_cm"]}, "$arr.v", "$$REMOVE"]}
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground 3rd](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jUxtlRm905K)

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly for small data, but I have near 45000 documents, and one field in each document containing an array of names.
For 10.000 documents, my final reduced array is 13700 names long and it takes 5 seconds to give the result. For 20.000 documents, 29500 names for 20sec. 
The $reduce and $setIntersection operators are very slow here. Is it possible to get the reduced array a faster way?

Comment: Updated with another 1.5 options (one query or two)

Comment: The second end solution is nice to me! Just unwind, then group with addToSet seems ok... Anyway, I found another solution with $unwind, then $sortByCount as my final guess was getting the most frequently used name. The build of a global array was only a partial step to my goal. Thanks for your clever solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Query

- put both in one array
- unwind
- at group time check the type(string or not) and put to the right group

*here types are different, in case they were the same type, we can do another trick like put the in an array of pairs `[[tag,cm] ...]` where first would be the tag and the second would be the cm, or array of documents
For perfomance if you test it send how it went if you can

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62a6121a91b564fc1e7e95a5)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$project": {"tags-dim": {"$concatArrays": ["$tags", "$dim_cm"]}}},
 {"$unwind": "$tags-dim"},
 {"$group": 
   {"_id": null,
    "tags": 
     {"$addToSet": 
       {"$cond": 
         [{"$eq": [{"$type": "$tags-dim"}, "string"]}, "$tags-dim",
          "$$REMOVE"]}},
    "dim_cm": 
     {"$addToSet": 
       {"$cond": 
         [{"$eq": [{"$type": "$tags-dim"}, "string"]}, "$$REMOVE",
          "$tags-dim"]}}}}])
```

Comment: It seems a bit tricky to assemble both arrays to dispatch them back later, but the use of $cond is nice to see and clear to understand. Thanks!